# Is single-output regression the same as univariate?

Tags: regression, multivariate-regression

Similarly, is multi-output regression the same as multivariate regression?

Comment: Your question is answered by hovering over the [tag:multivariate-regression] tag.

Comment: @whuber so do i need to repost the question?

Comment: No, but you might want to consider whether it needs to be asked!